# How to make Qt Websocket and QNetworkRequest (HTTP) to use the same connection?

Tags: c++, qt, poco-libraries, qtwebsockets, qtwebapp

Is it possible with Qt to upgrade a HTTP connection that handles the normal HTTP requests to a Websocket with the same connection?

I'm thinking about something like [this](http://k-line-print.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/server/cplus/src/WebSocketServer.cpp) with Poco libraries, but all done in Qt similar to  [QtWebApp](http://stefanfrings.de/qtwebapp/index-en.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is no and that is mostly because of specifics of the server side. And Qt just follows the protocol available and exposed by the server (HTTP/WebSocket) as mostly the client-side development framework and AFAIK won't be able to do the kind of transformation you want of going from HTTP to Websocket that are two different protocols. But of course, theoretically that can be done as long as both protocols able to use IP port 80. But that implies new unique sever and new unique client implementations.

We use both WebSocket and REST in our app. And WebSocket is for triggering the client by the server to do something. Client gets the "poke" from the server and starts normal JSON HTTP-based exchange with the server.

Somewhat relative link: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/276253/mixing-rest-and-websocket-in-the-same-api

Comment: That is what I figured, but still worth asking to double check. Will stick to Poco::Net for the server side then